# How to Check Email is validate or not?

Tags: .net, validation, email

> How to Check Email is validate or not ?

***(Example :- abc@yahoo.com -> Ok

abc@yahoo.con ->wrong)***

**I want to check validation for all world class level email address.**

Comment: did you mean check all domain ?.

Comment: it's worth pointing out that there are hundreds of new top level domains being launched very soon. `.con` is not one of the new ones, but your code *does* need to be aware of the new TLDs. Anything could be valid. Some examples [from the list](https://gtldresult.icann.org/application-result/applicationstatus/viewstatus) include `.bike`, `.baby`, `.inc`, and hundreds more. Also, `.co` and `.cm` are valid extensions, so even though they're common typos of `.com`, you can't automatically assume they're incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a string is a valid email you can use Regex,

Ex :

```
bool isEmail = Regex.IsMatch(emailString, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|asia|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel)\b)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

To validate if a mailbox exists or not , follow this article.

[Verify an Email Address](http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/)

> When you send an email to someone, the message goes to an SMTP server
>   which then looks for the MX (Mail Exchange) records of the email
>   recipient’s domain.
>
> For instance, when you send an email to hello@gmail.com, the mail
>   server will try to find the MX records for the gmail.com domain. If
>   the records exist, the next step would be to determine whether that
>   email username (hello in our example) is present or not.
>
> Using a similar logic, we can verify an email address from the
>   computer without actually sending a test message.

doing the same thing in .Net can be a tedious task.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use reverse email lookup services, but those won't be very reliable and many email providers deny reverse lookup requests. So I think your best bet is to first check that the email address is formatted correctly, then check the host domain exists, and then just send a verification email.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointless exercise. The only real way to do this validation is to send someone an email and require a response to verify that the email is in use. I also don't understand your example, abc@yahoo.com is not valid but :-abc@yahoo.com is? What? Do some simple validation that your user entered it correctly, that's it.

Comment: abc@yahoo.com is right email address but abc@yahoo.con is not right. I ask you how can i check it is valid or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$
```

Comment: Not Work Properly
------------------

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: hay nikunj just add start-end with '#' delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [MailAddress  Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) to validate the `string` and create a extension.

```
public static bool IsValidEmailAddress(this string email)
{
    try
    {
        var addr = new MailAddress(email);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Usage:***

```
string email = "test@yahoo.com";
if (email.IsValidEmailAddress())
{
 //TODO: Is email
}
```